# Adding a Unique Element to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects called seasons of length 300, and I trying to search through a certain property "Date" and add it to an array if it has not been found before. So far I have

```
var day=[];
for (var i=1; i<300; i++) {
    var found=false;
    for (var j=0; j<day.length; j++) {
        if (day[j]==seasons[i]["Date"]) {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
        if (!found) {
            day[day.length]=seasons[i]["Date"];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure where this is going wrong, and would appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `break` out of the inner for-loop, so the `if (!found)` block is never executed.

Just put it after the inner loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < day.length; j++) {
        if (day[j] == seasons[i]["Date"]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        day[day.length] = seasons[i]["Date"];
    }
}
```

Or do it in the if-block:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < day.length; j++) {
        if (day[j] == seasons[i]["Date"]) {
            day[day.length] = seasons[i]["Date"];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the latter solution is easier to understand.

Comment: @user10319 You may also replace `day[day.length]=seasons[i]["Date"];` with `day.push(seasons[i]["Date"]);`, it's a bit smaller to write and easier to read :)